# I need to wrap the text in excel using java

Tags: java

I write some data in excel using java.I need to wrap the particular cell as wrap.can any tell me what is the syntax for wrap text and how can I use it?

Comment: which java library are you using to write your excel file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jxl, you have to use setWrap(true):

```
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
cellFormat.setWrap(true);

sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 1, "A simple test message", cellFormat));    
sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 2, "An other text", cellFormat));
```

Edit:

To add a bold cell:

```
WritableFont cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.COURIER, 16);
cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

WritableCellFormat cellFormatBold = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 2, "An other text", cellFormatBold));
```

Comment: May I know how can I use bold in the same code?I need only one row should be in bold. how can I write code for it?

Answer (score 9):

Refer [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();  
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("Use \n with word wrap on to create a new line");

CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setWrapText(true);   //Wrapping text
cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Comment: I suggest you also provide a link to suggested API doc ... May be Apache POI.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Thats fine, still if you are struggling, post what you have tried. Will help u accordingly

Comment: FileOutputStream exlFileName= new FileOutputStream("D:\\Screenshot\\testExcel.xls"); WritableWorkbook exlWorkBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFileName); WritableSheet exlWorkSheet1 = exlWorkBook.createSheet("Preload data check",0); Label Sheet1cellContent = new Label(0,0,"LAST NAME"); exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent); This is my code how can I insert bold syntax in my code?

Answer (score 0):

To read an excel file you can use

- [Apache poi](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/poi-jdk14/releases/)

  In which the excel data's will read as

  ```
   Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
   CellStyle cs=wb.createCellStyle();
   cs.setWrapText(true);

   Cell cell=wb.getSheet(0).getRow(0).getCell();
   cell.setCellStyle(cs);
  ```

Comment: FileOutputStream exlFileName= new FileOutputStream("D:\\Screenshot\\testExcel.xls");
      WritableWorkbook exlWorkBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFileName);
      WritableSheet exlWorkSheet1 = exlWorkBook.createSheet("Preload data check",0);
      Label Sheet1cellContent = new Label(0,0,"LAST NAME");
     
      exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent);
 This is my code how can I insert bold syntax in it?

Comment: did u get the ans for ..wrapping

Comment: I need to write an excel with wrap text

Comment: Actually you are not using http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/poi-jdk14/releases/  right...

Comment: ya what should I do with that kark?first I need to download it?

Comment: Just download the jar and include it to your application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38316/discussion-between-kark-and-arun-kumar) if you can

Answer (score 0):

Auto Text Wrap:

```
public static void main(String []args){
String  str="Baraitha Katra Muzaffarpur RajaPuri {vimal} Ajmetigaet 8433221 vikaspuri New Delhi Faridabad India(.SSS)";
    String [] strArray=str.split(" ");
    ArrayList StrList=new ArrayList();
    String lineStr="";
    int start =0;
    for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
         lineStr=lineStr+strArray[i]+" ";
        if(lineStr.length()>30){
            String finalStr="";
            for(int j=start;j<i ;j++){
                finalStr=finalStr+strArray[j]+" ";
            }
            StrList.add(finalStr);
            lineStr="";
            start=i;
            i=i-1;              
        }       
    }
    StrList.add(lineStr);
System.out.println("Number of Lines-"+StrList.size());
for(int j=0;j<StrList.size();j++){
    System.out.println(StrList.get(j));

   }        
}
```